# R install.packages unable to find gcc

Tags: r

I am unable to compile packages from source on Windows. The issue seems to be related to resolving paths in the compilation step. Following the example from the [Rtools4 installation page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html), I get an error as follows:

```
> install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/jsonlite_1.7.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1051573 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'jsonlite' ...
** package 'jsonlite' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:\Rtools\mingw_64gcc  -I"C:/Users/<username>/DOCUME~1/R/R-41~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api       -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c base64.c -o base64.o
sh: line 1: C:Rtoolsmingw_64gcc: command not found
make: *** [C:/Users/<username>/DOCUME~1/R/R-41~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:238: base64.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'jsonlite'
* removing 'C:/Users/<username>/Documents/R/R-4.1.2/library/jsonlite'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/<username>/Documents/R/R-4.1.2/library/jsonlite'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jsonlite’ had non-zero exit status
```

I find it very odd that there's no file separators in the line that starts with `sh:`. There ought to be path separators, but the call to `gcc` seems to be missing them. Is there somewhere I can correct this path? I will also note that I have confirmed that gcc exists, but it's in `C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin`, not `C:\Rtools\mingw_64` as that line would seem to suggest that it's looking for it. I can confirm that the folder containing the gcc .exe file is on my path. Any suggestions on how to ensure that the correct path to gcc will be called is appreciated.

This is on a new installation of R 4.1.2 with RTools4.

For reference,

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.4.3 usethis_2.1.5 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_2.0.2    pkgload_1.2.4     R6_2.5.1          rlang_1.0.1       fastmap_1.1.0     tools_4.1.2      
 [7] pkgbuild_1.3.1    sessioninfo_1.2.2 cli_3.1.1         withr_2.4.3       ellipsis_0.3.2    remotes_2.4.2    
[13] rprojroot_2.0.2   lifecycle_1.0.1   crayon_1.4.2      brio_1.1.3        processx_3.5.2    purrr_0.3.4      
[19] callr_3.7.0       fs_1.5.2          ps_1.6.0          testthat_3.1.2    memoise_2.0.1     glue_1.6.1       
[25] cachem_1.0.6      compiler_4.1.2    desc_1.4.0        prettyunits_1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what the root cause of this issue was, but I was able to solve it by editing *both* Makeconf files at `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\R\R-4.1.2\etc\i386` and `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\R\R-4.1.2\etc\x64`. The two changes I made there were to set

```
RTOOLS40_HOME ?= c:/rtools
```

and

```
BINPREF = "$(RTOOLS40_ROOT)/mingw32/bin/"
```

If there is an explanation for why this solves the problem, I would appreciate hearing it!